# Index out of bounds exception when trying to swap the colums of a matrix

Tags: java, for-loop, matrix, indexoutofboundsexception

I'm trying to swap the colums of a matrix but I get an array index out of bouds exception. The matrix is the conversion of this picture: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NIwJ6.jpg

```
public static void especular(int [][] img){
        for (int f=0; f<img.length;f++)
            for (int c=0; c < img[f].length/2;c++){
                int aux = img[f][c];
                img[f][c] = img[f][img.length-1-c];
                img[f][img.length-1-c] =aux;
            }
    }
```

Comment: Is array a square matrix ?

Answer (score 0):

This is because you rows and columns are not same.

Consider an example : 
A 3x4 matrix

> [1,2,3]
>   [4,5,6]
>   [7,8,9]
>   [10,11,12]

now interchanging rows and columns

> [1,4,7,10]
>   [2,5,8,11]
>   [3,6,9,12]

This becomes a 4x3 matrix

---

## EDIT :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int [][] arr={{1,2,3},{4,5,6},{7,8,9}};
    printArray(arr);
    System.out.println();
    swapAllcolumns(arr);
}

public static void printArray(int [][] arr){
    for(int i =0; i<arr.length;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<arr[0].length;j++){
            System.out.print(arr[i][j]+" ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}

public static void swapAllcolumns(int [][] array){
    int [][] arr= new int[array.length][array[0].length];
    for(int i =0; i<arr.length;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<arr[0].length;j++){
            arr[i][j]=array[i][array[0].length-j-1];
        }
    }
    printArray(arr);
}
```

Output

```
1 2 3 
4 5 6 
7 8 9 

3 2 1 
6 5 4 
9 8 7
```

Comment: This isn't what I'm trying to do. With your example, what I'm trying to do is this: [3,2,1][6,5,4][9,8,7][12,11,10]

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like you've swapped the x and y coordinates in your 2d array.
I was able to reproduce the issue with this array:

> int[][] testArray = new int[482][446];

but this one worked:

> int[][] testArray = new int[446][482];

But I would focus on writing a loop that doesn't rely on image dimensions.